# How do I read last 20 digits of string in swift

Tags: swift

I have a swift program in whom I need to read the last 20 digits of a string.

Although I would prefer the last 20 digits the first 20 would also be fine if it makes it any easier.

And a way to read all Digits except for the last 20.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to mod this question down. String manipulation in Swift is curiously inconvenient in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting because the place you'd expect to find the answer would be the string functions -- where is the Swift equivalent of Javascript's String.substr() for example.

What you want is

```
String str = ...
str.substringFromIndex(advance(str.startIndex, 20)) // first 20 chars
str.substringFromIndex(advance(str.endIndex, -20)) // last 20 chars
```

In any case, you'll need to check if the str has fewer than 20 characters and just return the string itself.

You can determine the string length by
count(str) (older Swift versions) or str.characters.count (Swift 1.2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `suffix`:

```
String(yourString.characters.suffix(20))
```

Comment: Is this new? I get an error when I try that in a playground. (FYI I checked for myself and it was added in Swift 1.2. I need to update XCode on this machine)

Comment: The syntax is for Swift 2, but suffix is available in 1.2 as well.

Comment: The string functions in Swift are both opaque and not especially convenient to use. Something easily fixed, so — why?

Comment: This solution does not crash if the string length is less than 20.